# Retrieve contacts from Android Froyo 2.2

Tags: android, contacts, android-2.2-froyo

im using the following code segment to fetch contact names and numbers, it works fine on the emulator, but when i install the app in my Froyo 2.2.1, it just returns me the name, and instead of returning me the number it returns, 'null', can anyone help me solve this issue ?
will greatly appreciate any solution. Thanks

```
  ContentResolver r = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = r.query(People.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        // Let activity manage the cursor
       // startManagingCursor(cursor);
     //   Log.d(TAG, "cursor.getCount()=" + cursor.getCount());

        // Get value from content provider
        int nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(People.NAME);
        int numberIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(People.NUMBER);//OrThrow(People.NUMBER);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        do {
            String name = cursor.getString(nameIndex);
            String number = cursor.getString(numberIndex);
            s.append(name+ ": " + number + "\n");
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

Answer (score 2):

The People API is deprecated try using the ContactsContract API which was already introduced for android 2.0+.

You can look at [this blog post about using the contactscontract](http://blog.app-solut.com/2011/03/working-with-the-contactscontract-to-query-contacts-in-android/) or the [api documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html)

Comment: @arun If you want your application to support older API's and newer API's both, go through this [link](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/contacts.html). Refer the section **Supporting the old and new APIs in the same application**